# How to replace meta title and meta description in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

Sorry if my question was basic or stupid but please help me to solve this issue. I'm trying to change `<title>` and `<meta name="description" >` tags dynamically in wordpress. so this is what I tried in function.php file.

```
function changeMeta_2(){
    global $wpdb;
    $cur_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
    $basename = pathinfo($cur_url);
    $ebasename = $basename['filename'];
    if(is_numeric($ebasename)) {
    $url = explode('/', $basename['dirname']);
    $basename = explode('.', $url[count($url)-2]);
    $ebasename = $basename[0];
    }
    $pageName = $ebasename;



    $arraylist_subcat  = array("car","bike","boat","xxxx","yyyy","zzz","mmmm");
    $arraylist_maincat = array("aus","ind","usa","uae");


    $category_id = get_term_by('slug',$pageName, 'category');   
    $category_parentid  = get_term_by('id', $category_id->parent, 'category');   
    $parent_slug =  $category_parentid->slug;



   if ( is_page()) {        
        if ( in_array($pageName,$arraylist_maincat) ) {         
                $metaTitle = 'Browse  '.$pageName.' | Some txt title | mysite.com';
                $metaDescription = 'some of custome blablaaaaa text description  '.$pageName.' some of custome blablaaaaa text description ';                               
                echo '<title>'.$metaTitle.'</title>';
                echo '<meta name="description" content="'.$metaDescription.'"/>';                   
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'changeMeta_2' );
```

In the above code I'm trying to change the title tag and meta description for term id which are matching with array values (in_array condition).

Everything works fine, but problem is instead of override(replace) `<title>` tag is appending in head. Its not changing it appending. please someone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the Yoast plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/ With that plugin you can manage your SEO data per page..

Comment: i m trying in coding, not by plugin. please tell me how to replace title tag using coding in function php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody coming to this question in the future: This functionality can be accomplished using the [Yoast SEO plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/).

**However**, if you do want to still do this yourself....

In order to modify the title, rather than the `wp_head` hook, you need to be using the filters that actually allow you to **modify** the title: [wp_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/)

And you can / should use the `wp_head` in order to **add** the meta description (see the docs here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress)

**Also note** there's easier ways to get the page title, mentioned below...

For the title, your code would look something like so:

```
function changeTitle($title, $sep, $seplocation){
    global $wpdb;

    // NOTE: This is the HARD way to get the page title, and is unreliable...
    $cur_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
    $basename = pathinfo($cur_url);
    $ebasename = $basename['filename'];

    if(is_numeric($ebasename)) {
        $url = explode('/', $basename['dirname']);
        $basename = explode('.', $url[count($url)-2]);
        $ebasename = $basename[0];
    }

    $pageName = $ebasename;

    // NOTE: Why not get pagename this way?
    global $post;
    $pageName = $post->post_title;

    // or if you need the slug...
    $pageName = $post->post_slug;

    $arraylist_subcat  = array("car","bike","boat","xxxx","yyyy","zzz","mmmm");
    $arraylist_maincat = array("aus","ind","usa","uae");


    $category_id = get_term_by('slug',$pageName, 'category');   
    $category_parentid  = get_term_by('id', $category_id->parent, 'category');   
    $parent_slug =  $category_parentid->slug;



   if ( is_page()) {        
        if ( in_array($pageName,$arraylist_maincat) ) {         
                $title = 'Browse  '.$pageName.' | Some txt title | mysite.com';                 
        }
    }

    return $title;
}

add_action( 'wp_title', 'changeTitle', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 3):

How document title is generated has changed since Wordpress v4.4.0. Now `wp_get_document_title` dictates how title is generated:

```php
/**
 * Displays title tag with content.
 *
 * @ignore
 * @since 4.1.0
 * @since 4.4.0 Improved title output replaced `wp_title()`.
 * @access private
 */
function _wp_render_title_tag() {
    if ( ! current_theme_supports( 'title-tag' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<title>' . wp_get_document_title() . '</title>' . "\n";
}
```

Here is the code from v5.4.2. Here are the filters you can use to manipulate title tag:

```php
function wp_get_document_title() {
    /**
    * Filters the document title before it is generated.
    *
    * Passing a non-empty value will short-circuit wp_get_document_title(),
    * returning that value instead.
    *
    * @since 4.4.0
    *
    * @param string $title The document title. Default empty string.
    */
    $title = apply_filters( 'pre_get_document_title', '' );
    if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
        return $title;
    }
    // --- snipped ---
    /**
    * Filters the separator for the document title.
    *
    * @since 4.4.0
    *
    * @param string $sep Document title separator. Default '-'.
    */
    $sep = apply_filters( 'document_title_separator', '-' );

    /**
    * Filters the parts of the document title.
    *
    * @since 4.4.0
    *
    * @param array $title {
    *     The document title parts.
    *
    *     @type string $title   Title of the viewed page.
    *     @type string $page    Optional. Page number if paginated.
    *     @type string $tagline Optional. Site description when on home page.
    *     @type string $site    Optional. Site title when not on home page.
    * }
    */
    $title = apply_filters( 'document_title_parts', $title );
    // --- snipped ---
    return $title;
}
```

So here are two ways you can do it.

First one uses `pre_get_document_title` filter which short-circuits the title generation and hence more performant if you are not going make changes on current title:

```php
function custom_document_title( $title ) {
    return 'Here is the new title';
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'custom_document_title', 10 );
```

Second way uses `document_title_separator` and `document_title_parts` hooks for the title and the title seperator that are executed later in the function, after title is generated using functions like `single_term_title` or `post_type_archive_title` depending on the page and about to be outputted:

```php
// Custom function should return a string
function custom_seperator( $sep ) {
   return '>';
}
add_filter( 'document_title_separator', 'custom_seperator', 10 );

// Custom function should return an array
function custom_html_title( $title ) {
   return array(
     'title' => 'Custom Title',
     'site'  => 'Custom Site'
    );
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'custom_html_title', 10 );
```